# Python customtkinter AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_root'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror, customtkinter

i just took over a project in python after a year and i wanted to rebuild it with customtkinter using the documentation. Here is the code:

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter
from pytube import YouTube
from PIL import Image

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("system")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("800x760")
app.title("YouTube Unlocked")

logo = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("G:\\ytdownloader\\assets\\icon.png"), size=(260,190))
logoDisplay = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="", image=logo)
logoDisplay.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

linkLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="Video link", font=("Arial", 15))
linkLabel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

linkTextbox = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, width=400)
linkTextbox.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

radio_var = tkinter.IntVar(0)
radiobutton_1 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(app, text="Video", variable=radio_var, value=1)
radiobutton_2 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(app, text="Audio", variable=radio_var, value=2)
radiobutton_1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
radiobutton_2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

app.mainloop()
```

But after writing the radio buttons code (always from the documentation) I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\ytdownloader\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    radio_var = tkinter.IntVar(0)
  File "C:\Users\gp_ga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 564, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Users\gp_ga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 372, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_root'
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks! (by the way if it's a bad english I want to let you know that i'm using google translate)

Comment: Did you try `customtkinter.IntVar`?  Since you didn't create a Tk root, the library has not been initialized.

Comment: If you want to supply an initial value when creating a Tkinter Var object, that's the *second* parameter - more commonly written as a `value=` keyword parameter.  The first parameter is a widget (defaulting to the root window), which indirectly specifies the `Tk()` instance that owns the Var.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tkinter.IntVar()` already has a default value of `0`. The [`documentation`](https://tkdocs.com/pyref/intvar.html) says the following about the arguments that `tkinter.IntVar()` can take:

> tkinter.IntVar(master=None, value=None, name=None)

Since `master` comes first and you provided `0` as the first positional argument, it believes that it is the `master` argument. What you want to do is specify the argument `value`. Like so:

```
radio_var = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
```